# Applying functions to only certain elements in a list

Tags: r, dataframe, posixct, posixlt

I have several data sets, each with a date_time column that is formatted differently. I put the data frames into a list so that I can apply functions to clean all of the data at once. Here's some mock data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(date_time = c("01/01/17 1:00:02 AM", "01/01/17 10:00:02 PM", "01/01/17 12:00:02 AM"))
df2 <- data.frame(date_time = c("1/1/2016 1:00", "1/1/2016 11:00", "1/1/2016 13:00"))
df.list <- list(df1=df1, df2=df2)
```

The date_time column is the only column that differs between the data sets, so I have two different functions to change the columns to POSIX format:

```
change_POSIX <- function(df){
  df[["date_time"]] <- as.POSIXct(df[["date_time"]],format="%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S %p", tz="UTC")
  return(df)
}

change_POSIX_2 <- function(df){
  df[["date_time"]] <- as.POSIXct(df[["date_time"]],format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz="UTC")
  return(df)
  }
```

My question is, how can I apply the function change_POSIX to data sets resembling df1 in my list, and apply change_POSIX_2 to data sets like df2? I've been using `df.list <- lapply(df.list, change_POSIX)`, for example, to change df1, but it returns NA for df2.

How can I apply the first function to some data frames in the list, while applying the other function to the other data frames in the list?

Using R version 3.5.1, Mac OS X 10.13.6

Comment: Maybe use `tryFormats = c("%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S %p", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")` in `as.POSIXct`

Comment: @GKi suggestion seems to be better than this one: if you know what function to apply to whatdata set, put the functions in a list, `change.list <- list(change_POSIX = change_POSIX,change_POSIX_2 = change_POSIX_2)` and then `mapply(function(x, f){f(x)}, df.list, change.list)`.

Comment: @GKi This is a great, simple solution; thanks!